# In Postgres Procedure, create Article and Tags then return created Article and Tags

Tags: postgresql

I have a Database that is meant to store Articles and Tags. Tags are created automatically with new Articles, to make handling them easier. The max amount of tags is limited to 5 by the backend. Heres what the tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE tag(
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);


CREATE TABLE article(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name text,
    description text,
    author text references profile(name)
);

CREATE TABLE tag_article(
    tag text REFERENCES tag(name),
    article uuid REFERENCES article(id),
    UNIQUE (tag, article)
);
```

I have created a stored procedure to create the article, create all the tags (unless they exist) and then connect them using the tag_article table:

```
create or replace procedure create_article(
    author text,
    name text,
    description text,
    tags text[]
)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin

    INSERT INTO tag(name)
        SELECT v
            FROM unnest(tags) g(v)
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

    WITH article(id) AS(
        INSERT INTO article(author, name, description) 
            values(author,name,description) 
        RETURNING id
    )
    INSERT INTO tag_article(tag,article)
        SELECT g.v, article.id FROM
            unnest(tags) g(v), article;
    
    COMMIT;

END $$;
```

Now I need a way to return the tags that have been created (if there were any) and the article. I know for the tags I can just use returning *, since that will give me only the created tags.
But I also need a way to forward this to the caller of the procedure. I also need to do the same with the article. The problem there is, I am already returning the id, so I don't know how I could just return the entire row with it.

So how can I modifiy this code in order to

- Return all the newly created tags, including the creation date and other information that might later be added to the tag table or just an empty set
- Return the Article, which may also receive more attributes

Comment: Use a function instead of a procedure and you can return whatever you need.

Comment: Whats the reason I can't use a procedure for this? Because I do need transactions and I can't use them with functions

Comment: As it stands your procedure is no different then function with regards to transaction. A function will commit on completion, so there is no reason to use a procedure. As to returning a row use `RETURN *`. For how to return a set from a function see [Returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) 42.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY

Comment: _„A function will commit on completion”_ - this is not true - the client has to commit explicitly or set autocommit mode. But the advice is still valid - you should use a function `select create_article(?,?,?,?)`. Procedures are useful for code that requires more than one transaction, which is not the case here.